# Restrict access to text formats for certain role

Tags: 7, nodes, input-formats

For every user with role `company manager` i have made tab `My company`(in user profile) where user can see `node_edit` of their company(node). And i need to set default format to `plain-text` and hide text-format drop down list only for this role. Ofc. i can do this for every user, i can change settings in my content type field settings, but this way the other users will not see it too.

Any suggestions? how can i achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean when you say, "where user can see `node_edit` of their company(node)"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by some coding. If it is okay to make a custom module then it can be done via [hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)

In this hook get a debug statement to get the form id for your node edit page. Now in that page you need to get the type of node being edited. So there are 3 things to look for.

1. Get the form_id for the node edit page. Then use this in a switch-case statement to perform your logic.
2. Then get the Node type that is being edited, from the URL. So if you are in a edit page then the URL will be like, http://example.com/node/14/edit. For arg(2) you will get the node id. Perform a node_load and call [node_type_get_name($node)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_type_get_name/7) or just a simple database query to node table by node id will do it for you.
3. Check for the User role and decide to show/hide the select box.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    global $user;
    switch($form_id) {
       case "node-edit_form" : //may differ as I am only giving a demo
         //Add your logic
         $nid = arg(2); //Add some isset check will be good and filter_xss() for security purpose. 
         $node_type = db_select('node', 'n')->fields('n', array('type'))->condition('nid', $nid, '=')->execute()->fetchObject();
         if($node_type->type == 'your_needed_type') {
              if(array_key_exists('company manager', $user->roles)) {
                  $form['#after_build'][] = 'mymodule_your_needed_type_node_form_after_build';
              }
         }
       break;
    }
}

function mymodule_your_needed_type_node_form_after_build($form) {
    // We want this on a specific field
    $form[LANGUAGE_NONE]['0']['format']['#access'] = FALSE;
    return $form;
}
```

I think this will solve the issue for you. You can do some R&D and make it more efficient like to add more checks.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use the [Better Formats module](http://drupal.org/project/better_formats), it gives a lot of possibilities to you to control text format selection.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of coding, this can be achieved from admin configuration in drupal 7.

Go to

> Configurations > Content Authoring > Text formats

at this page, you can set restriction against your roles.

Answer (score 0):

A simple but relevant sledgehammer approach would be to revoke permission to use anything but the `plain-text` format, using [user_role_revoke_permissions](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_role_revoke_permissions/7).  (Similarly, if you want to *add* permissions to use a given text format for a given role, use [user_role_grant_permissions](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_role_grant_permissions/7).)

```
user_role_revoke_permissions(DRUPAL_AUTHENTICATED_RID,
   array(... 'use text format filtered_html', ...));
```